# mysql host on internet using hp cloud and xeround

Tags: mysql, hp-cloud-services

I am new to the 'cloud' concept I have a Java based application for data entry which  runs well on my LAN.

On my LAN I install:

- MySql
- Configure Instance ( user name - `root`, pass - `******`)
- Dump dummy database `entry_db` that is in `raw` format

Then I have a jar executable file which when runs, displays a login screen.

I manage to successfully log in using predefined ID and PASSWORD (user - `config` pass - `******`)

After logging in I configure(d):

- Database Type
- Database IP
- User Name (`Root`)
- Password `****`
- Database Name ( It auto selects database named `entry_db`)

In another window I configure(d) Network File Sharing Location:

- file shared location
- image path
- back up data path
- config file location in xml

(Note - When I select file shared location, all other files take the same path automatically)

Then I create `Admin account` rather than `Supervisor account` or `operator account` and login with the Admin account and I can now upload data and distribute to all operators.

Here is my problem:

- I configure a cloud computer on **Hp Cloud**  (they provide me a static ip) and then import database from xeround.com.

I now have a dns and port number and also a log in form using **MY PHP CLIENT**
How can I package all this to the same executable jar file to be used from anywhere?
How can I use it just like on my LAN from the web?

What is the optimal configuration for this?

Comment: If you want to get readers , please make some effort while writing your question : do not abuse of uppercase and bold...

Comment: Thanks i will careful next time can any one pls help me on this issue

Answer (score 0):

I work in Xeround.

I have read your question and I wanted to point out a couple of things;  you should use the DNS in the connection string where you used to put hostname/IP of the MYSQL server machine and the port number where you used to put the MySQL default port (3306).
 
Other than that you can connect from anywhere there is access to the instance. I suggest that if your jar runs in the HP cloud you create your Xeround database instance there as well (this will yield improved performance).
 
If you still need help, we will be more than happy to help you. Just send us a quick email to support@xeround.com and we'll take it from there.

Cheers,
Yuval